# Retrieve data from a local nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I made a little test page which looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <title>Get JSON Value</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script>

        var json = $.getJSON("../js/report.json", function(data) 
        {
            var items = [];

            $.each(data, function (key, value)
            {
                items.push(key + " " + value);  
            });

            alert(items[3]);
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

It fetches the data from a local JSON file stored on my local server.

The JSON object looks something like this:

```
{
  "reportTitle": "Results",
  "inlineAssets": false,
  "stats": {
    "suites": 7,
    "tests": 13,
    "passes": 11,
    "pending": 0,
    "failures": 2,
    "start": "2016-08-11T13:30:48.362Z",
    "end": "2016-08-11T13:31:29.433Z",
    "duration": 41071,
    ...
}
```

`alert(items[2]);` gives me `stats [object Object]`
`alert(items[3]);` gives me `suites [object Object]`

Is it possible for me to retrieve the number of `suites`, `tests` and `passes`?
So the output of the alert would be `suites 7`, `tests 13` and `passes 11`.

EDIT:

Ideally I'd like to store these values in variables of their own instead of just `alert` or `console.log`.

EDIT for `david`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXC0g.png)

EDIT 3:

I've tried:

`console.log(items[2].suites);` => `undefined`

Comment: instead of using alert, try using `console.log` like this `console.log(items[3])`. After that, inspect element to see the result.

Comment: @david It just gives you the exact same result

Comment: you can click the down arrow on the result to see the deeper answer.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to retrieve number of `suites`, `tests`, `passes`.

Retrieving number of `suites` => `items[3].stats.suites`

Retrieving number of `tests` => `items[3].stats.tests`

Retrieving number of `passes` => `items[3].stats.passes`

Replace `3` inside the brackets with whatever index number you want.

---

**EDIT**

You can forget my answer above. This is the real answer. I have modified your code a bit to get your desired answer.

```
var items=[];
function recursive(data){
    $.each(data, function (key, value)
    {
        if (value instanceof Object) {
            recursive(value);
        } else {
            items.push(key + " " + value);
        }
    });
}

var json = $.getJSON("report.json", function(data) 
{
    recursive(data);
    console.log(items[2]); // return 'suites 7'
    console.log(items[3]); // return 'tests 13'
    console.log(items[4]); // return 'passes 11'
});
```

Since there is an object inside an object, I have to use recursive to trace all the data.

Answer (score 2):

You did not push stats to items array. Thats why you can`t got it data. 
Try to do it simpler

```
var json = $.getJSON("../js/report.json", function(data) {
    var stats = data.stats;
    $.each(stats, function(key, val){
       alert(key + " " + val)
    });
});
```

[Simulation example](http://plnkr.co/edit/N792ZR2oKdFlDEGWaozn?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've just tried `console.log(items[3].suites);` and the result comes back as `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Same goes for `console.log(items[2].suites);`

Comment: Edited, i guess now my answer will help you